# Printing two arraylists simultaneously c#

Tags: c#, selenium, arraylist

I need to print these two arrays simultaneously but I cannot figure out a way to do it.

Here is my code, it works - now how do I add the array name?

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList name = new ArrayList();

list.Add("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/header/div/h2");
name.Add("Projects Header"); 

list.Add("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/header/div/button/span[1]/span");
name.Add("Hamburger Menu");

list.Add("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/button");
name.Add("Create Project Button");

list.Add("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button/span[1]");
name.Add("Join Project Button");



foreach (string xpath in list)
{             
    if (Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Size != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("element => " + xpath + " <= succesfully loaded!");                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write what result you are expecting. I am not really sure what you want

Comment: Why use two separate lists at all? Why not have a class with 2 properties: `Selector` and `Name` and store them in a single `List<T>` (give up on the unused/unloved `ArrayList`)

Comment: @TimaGegewepe I need to check the elements for which I need the xpath to make sure they're not null, I also need to display a name I will give to each element in order for me to know what each xpath corresponds to.
example:
xpath1="xxx"
xpath1_name="this element"
I want to display:                *xxx with the name this element was succesfully loaded*

Comment: @MiguelAcosta That does not make sense, this _should_ be one `List<T>` (not `ArrayList`)  of a custom type that contains the two properties you need.

Comment: So if you are assigning them by iterating through elements, why don't you create a class that will include both? Then create objects and add them to an array.

Comment: This whole thing is really not a good idea. You should just declare your locators as `By` and forget the list. Then for each locator, create a NUnit Assert for existence. Also, in your loop you are checking for `.Size` but using `.FindElement`. If the element isn't found, it's going to throw an exception before checking the size... and comparing the size to null makes no sense. It should be something like `By projectsHeaderLocator = By.Id("something");` and then `Assert.IsTrue(Driver.FindElements(projectsHeaderLocator).Count > 0, "Verify projects header exists.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend creating a class:

```
class Model
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string attribute { get; set; }
}
```

After that, just fill the object and put it inside the list

```
List<Model> list = new List<Model>();

Model model = new Model();
model.name = "test";
model.attribute = "your Attribute";

foreach (var item in list)
{
     // you can get name and attribute here
     item.name;
     item.attribute;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For `attribute`, don't use `string` use `By` instead so you aren't restricted to one locator type (e.g. you can use `By.Id()`, `By.CssSelector()`, and so on).